# Create 1 route for 2 urls ( one that has params and one that doesn't)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to push a user through vue-router to one single route but in one case this route would have params and on the other case it wouldn't have params. When it has params, I would show other components inside the page. So everything depends on whether I have a param or not.
But when I try that out I get an error and I can't really pass my params to the route.
This is my route

```
    {
       path : '/template',
       name : 'Template',
       component : Template 

    },
```

I have a route that is /template that has no params.
So it'd look like this :

```
 this.$router.push("/template")
```

And another one that has the same name with the same route but that has params

```
 this.$router.push({path : 'template', params:{ id }})
```

Yet, when I try to push the second one, it would ignore the values of the params. And I need these 2 routes to have shared components so it wouldn't be a good practice to have 2 routes with same components.
Here is the error I'm getting
Path "template" was passed with params but they will be ignored. Use a named route alongside params instead.

Comment: Can't you declare the `params` route as a child of your main route and thus modify the `path` to `/template/:id`?

Comment: It didn't work out when I did that.
It's actually CRUD operations.
I Have a post request and a put request and for the put request i need the id
When I did what you said it'd ignore the one with no params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query instead of params.

```js
this.$router.push({path : 'template', query:{ id }})
```

```html
<OtherComponent v-if="$route.query.id" />
```

Comment: thats what I did

Comment: Could you please explain why?